# Pull Product Data to WooCommerce from ODBC connection to MS SQL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, odbc

My client has a WooCommerce site and also a Stock System called Kerridge which I believe uses MSSQL as a database.

Does anyone know if it's possible to sync the Product Data such as Stock Amount into Woo directly.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: API - https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/